# Error in BulkRequest java API in Elasticsearch : "The number of object passed must be even but was [1]"

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to use map with Bulk Insert Api of ElasticSearch Java Api

```
public  void bulkInsert(List<Map<String,String>> listOfObjects ){

    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();

    Iterator<Map<String,String>> itr = listOfObjects.iterator();

    if (itr.hasNext()){
        Map<String,String> document = itr.next();
        bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex(index, type)
                .setSource(document));
    }

    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();


    if (bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
        System.out.println(bulkResponse.buildFailureMessage());
    }   

}
```

And I am calling this with

```
Map<String,String> jsonMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    jsonMap.put("name", fullName.toString());
    jsonMap.put("file", file);

    List<Map<String,String>> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    listOfObjects.add(jsonMap);
    indexService.bulkInsert(listOfObjects);
```

I am getting following exception
**The number of object passed must be even but was [1]**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I got the fix :
Use `Map<String, Object>` instead of `Map <String,String>`

```
Map<String,Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    jsonMap.put("name", fullName.toString());
    jsonMap.put("file", file);

    List<Map<String,Object>> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
    listOfObjects.add(jsonMap);
    indexService.bulkInsert(listOfObjects);
```

From [ES java api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/7.5/java-docs-index.html#java-docs-index-generate-using-map);

**Using Map**

**Map is a key:values pair collection. It represents a JSON structure:**

```
Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
json.put("user","kimchy");
json.put("postDate",new Date());
json.put("message","trying out Elasticsearch");
```

Comment: Looks like there is a `jsonBuilder().startObject()` object to help with these types of issues.